# Как задать задержку перед прокруткой слайда?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slick.js

Как задать задержку перед прокруткой слайда? В настройках slick slider не нашел. Может есть какой-то другой путь.

JS-код слайдера:

```
    $(".intro__slider").slick({
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 6000,
    dots: true,
    dotsClass: "intro__dots",
    arrows: false
  });

  var introTitle = $(".intro__title"),
      introSlide = $(".intro__slide");

  $(".intro__slider").on("beforeChange", function () {
    introTitle.addClass("intro__title_hidden");
    introSlide.addClass("intro__slide_overlayed");
  });

  $(".intro__slider").on("afterChange", function () {
    introTitle.removeClass("intro__title_hidden");
    introSlide.removeClass("intro__slide_overlayed");
  });
```

[Код на кодпене](https://codepen.io/SilencerWeb/pen/mwvONj)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31222456/delay-pause-slick-slide-function

Comment: не помогло, прокручивает слайд после нажатия на кнопку, потом когда проходит время, указанное в setTimeout, прокручивает еще раз. И нужно чтобы при свайпе тоже работало, не только при нажатии на кнопку.

Comment: А как вы себе представляете задержку на свайпе? Зажал, повел, а она как тормозной интерфейс через полсекунды повторило?